# Creating custom connection pool in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hikaricp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm writing a Spring Boot application which connects with Snowflake Data Warehouse and execute SQL queries on it.
I have written a Configuration class for configuring Datasource for connecting to Snowflake Data Warehouse as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class DBConfig {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DBConfig.class);
    @Bean
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
        logger.info("-----Configuring JDBCTemplate------");
        SnowflakeBasicDataSource dataSource = new SnowflakeBasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setServerName("<myserver>.snowflakecomputing.com");
        dataSource.setUser("<my_username>");
        dataSource.setPassword("<my_password>");
        dataSource.setWarehouse("DEMO_WH");
        dataSource.setDatabaseName("DEMO_DB");
        dataSource.setSchema("PUBLIC");
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

My pom.xml looks like as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.vaibhav</groupId>
    <artifactId>snowflake-1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>snowflake-1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.snowflake</groupId>
            <artifactId>snowflake-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have to use a connection pool for this data source in my Spring boot application.

How can I use HikariCP connection pool in my application which can work perfectly fine with my Customized DataSource?

**------EDIT --- Thanks for providing solution, finally my working code looks like**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class DBConfig {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DBConfig.class);

    @Bean
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
        logger.info("-----Configuring JDBCTemplate------");

        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName("net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver");
        // config.setDataSourceProperties(properties);
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:snowflake://<myserver>.snowflakecomputing.com/?warehouse=DEMO_WH&db=DEMO_DB&schema=PUBLIC");
        config.setUsername("<my_username>");
        config.setPassword("<my_password>");
        HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(config);

        return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for leaving example of working code. It saved me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See setting [SnowflakeDriver with Hikari](https://snowflakecommunity.force.com/s/question/0D50Z00008ELVe5SAH/connection-pooling-using-jdbc):

> ```
>   HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();    
>   config.setDriverClassName("com.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver");    
>   config.setDataSourceProperties(properties);    
>   config.setJdbcUrl(connectStr);    
>   HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this, I will try this solution and will update

Comment: This solution worked or me, I will post the updated code, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If spring-jdbc is being included, Spring will automatically create JdbcTemplate based on the available DataSource. So If the above answers does not satisfy you, you may just try:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class DBConfig {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DBConfig.class);

    // TAKE NOTE THAT THIS MIGHT ALREADY BE DONE BY SPRING
    @Bean
    protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate( DataSource dataSource )
    {
        return new JdbcTemplate( dataSource );
    }    

    @Bean
    protected DataSource makeDataSource() throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
        logger.info("-----Configuring JDBCTemplate------");
        SnowflakeBasicDataSource dataSource = new SnowflakeBasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setServerName("<myserver>.snowflakecomputing.com");
        dataSource.setUser("<my_username>");
        dataSource.setPassword("<my_password>");
        dataSource.setWarehouse("DEMO_WH");
        dataSource.setDatabaseName("DEMO_DB");
        dataSource.setSchema("PUBLIC");
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, however I want to use customized datasource in place of AutoConfigured datasource

Answer (score 1):

Hikari is default connection pool in Spring-boot 2+

> We have nothing to do if we want to use Hikari in an application based
>   on Spring Boot 2.x.

You can set different properties of connection pool thru application.yml / application.properties. Below is an example of application.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource
    hikari:
      maximumPoolSize: 4 # Specify maximum pool size
      minimumIdle: 1 # Specify minimum pool size
      driver-class-name: com.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver
```

This is a [useful link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-hikari) for configuring Hikari CP.

Comment: As you can see in my code, I have disable DatasourceAutoConfiguration for providing customized SnowflakeDataSource, so I dont think this will work with AutoConfiguration disabled.