# How to use HikariPool to connect to Snowflake - SpringBoot, Gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, hikaricp

I am trying to connect to `Snowflake` using `HikariPool`. I am using `SpringBoot` and `Gradle`.

I added these dependencies to Gradle

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
implementation 'net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.12.16'
implementation group: 'com.zaxxer', name: 'HikariCP', version: '5.0.0'
```

And config file looks like this:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class SnowflakeRepositoryConfig {

    @Bean
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Value("${repository.snowflake.url}") String jdbcUrl,
                              @Value("${repository.snowflake.user}") String user,
                              @Value("${repository.snowflake.password}") String password){
        
        log.info("-----Configuring JDBCTemplate------");
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName("net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver");
        config.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
        config.setUsername(user);
        config.setPassword(password);
        HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(config);

        return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }
}
```

**Application.yml**

```
repository:
  snowflake:
    url: jdbc:snowflake://nw99383.eu-west-2.snowflakecomputing.com/?db=TEST_DB&warehouse=SF_TUTS_WH&schema=PUBLIC&tracing=ALL
    user: ****
    password: ****
```

And I am getting following error:

```
13:56:42.353 [main] ERROR net.snowflake.client.core.HttpUtil - Response status line reason: Forbidden
13:56:42.358 [main] ERROR net.snowflake.client.core.HttpUtil - Response content: <html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
</body>
</html>

13:56:43.371 [main] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: HTTP status=403.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please update Snowflake account URL and try:
nw99383.eu-west-2.**aws**.snowflakecomputing.com/

Comment: I did and I have this error now: `Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class`

Comment: Please check if this resolution helps: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-failed-to-configure-data-source

Comment: I have specified         `config.setDriverClassName("net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver");`and also have it in my application.yml file

Comment: Not a hikaripool user but got the below post with a connection snippet that sounds to work with Snowflake. please review: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845645/creating-custom-connection-pool-in-spring-boot-application

Comment: I fixed my url like you said and added `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})`from example that you sent me. I was tring to implement that one in first place. Now It works Thank you!